# Convergence of $\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{\ln(1/x)} \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does $$\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} \mathrm{d}x$$ converge? [WA says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%200%20to%201%20%28ln%281/x%29%29%5E%281/3%29%20dx)  it is equal to $\Gamma(4/3)$, however calculating the antiderivative seems approachless to me and can't compare to other functions. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not delete questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question; deleting the question is disrespectful of their effort and prevents others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $x=e^{-t}$ in the integral.  You should end up with

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t} \,t^{1/3}$$